# How to specify where windows will open when using two monitors

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors

I'm connecting my TV to my Dell Vostro V131 Ubuntu 11.10 via HDMI.
I'm trying to figure out how to determine on which display new windows will open.
I've searched for an answer for a week now and i found nothing helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: I think placing windows for newly opened applications is a function of the window manager you are using. You may wish to specify which one you use.